# Multiple Legends the same for ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, legend

I'm trying to create a single legend for multiple maps. Each map is for a different year, and has the same set of polygons. The polygons on each map display a different range of values.

For example data for 2010 is from min 3 to max 10 and data from 2016 is from min 5 to max 12. I want a single legend that shows the entire range of values, from min 3 to max 12.

How can I create a single legend that covers the range of values on both maps?

Comment: Merge them and do symbology. Use that symbology on originals.

Answer (score 2):

You have different options.

1. Make the different legends independently, convert them to graphics, and build a nicer legend from the pieces.
2. Make the different legends and place them side-by-side, without a border or the word *legend* showing, so that it looks like one legend.
3. Put all the layers you want in your legend in one data frame.  Turn off the duplicates in the data frame but have them in the Legend Items.  In the Legend Properties dialog box uncheck *Only display layers that are checked on in the table of contents*.